# goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:jlink failed: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()" because "dir" is null

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, jlink

I am trying to build (have built) a JavaFX application using maven and IntelliJ. However when I try to run the maven javafx:jlink I keep getting an error saying `Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:jlink (default-cli) on project TheHydrant: Execution default-cli of goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:jlink failed: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()" because "dir" is null`

The code is all on github the link is: https://github.com/Binxlola/TheHydrant

Below is also my current pom.xml file and it's contents and a link to the structure of the project. When i grab files I don't use a full path but rather just the file name as all resources should be complied into the same directory as the classes that uses them. With the exception of some icons which I will grab using "/file.ext"

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.TheHydrant</groupId>
    <artifactId>TheHydrant</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.27.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                    <compress>2</compress>
                    <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                    <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                    <launcher>TheHydrant</launcher>
                    <jlinkImageName>The-Hydrant</jlinkImageName>
                    <jlinkZipName>TheHydrant</jlinkZipName>
                    <mainClass>com.TheHydrant.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

[PROJECT STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW71K.png)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: What result do you get if execute this goal from command line?

Comment: @Andrey I get the same error. I am working on trying to get a reproducible piece of code, but I find this error so vague I find it hard to narrow down.

Comment: @Andrey I'm having the same issue. I'm trying to follow the steps for creating a runtime image at [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/), but I'm getting this error.